# How can I make Web API serialize DateTime in any object into number of milliseconds since 1970?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In my ASP.NET web service I need all my dates to be serialized to JSON as numbers which represent a number of milliseconds passed since 1970 please. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json serializer. What do I need to do to set it up this way?

UPDATE:
the available documentation (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) only mentions serializing a single object with custom settings, what i am looking for is the default serialization settings that would govern serialization of any object

Comment: Before someone answers, did you look at the [relevant documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)? It makes mention there of several different converters and it's hinted that you could implement your own.

Comment: Is this Web API? ASMX? WCF? MVC?

Comment: @mason it's ASP.NET

Comment: Web API, ASMX, WCF, and MVC are all part of ASP.NET. Which specifically are you using? How you specify default settings is different depending on what framework you're using.

Comment: i think it's web API, although i am not sure, do you know how to find out?

Comment: Look at your controllers. Do they inherit from System.Web.Mvc.Controller? Or from System.Web.Http.ApiController?

Comment: it's `ApiController`

Comment: Look at the [Web API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_dates). You can set it to use Microsoft JSON Date Format.

Comment: it doesn't work because there are only 2 customizable options: 
1. enum: either iso date or ms-json date, 2. datestringformat (which cannot be used to get total number of milliseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what worked:

```
public class MyConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        return (type == typeof(DateTime) || type == typeof(DateTime?));
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new NotSupportedException("An attempt to read a date using a write-only converter from DateTime -> number of milliseconds since 1970.");
    }

    static readonly long ticksTo1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            var date = (DateTime)value;
            var unixDateSpan = new TimeSpan(date.Ticks - ticksTo1970);
            var milliseconds = (long)unixDateSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
            writer.WriteValue(milliseconds);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("A value of unexpected type where a DateTime value is expected.");
        }
    }
}

public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    [NonAction]
    protected JsonResult<T> MyJson<T>(T data)
    {
        var result = this.Json(data);
        result.SerializerSettings.Converters.Insert(0, new MyConverter());
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I would get the ticks of the 1970 date subtract it from the ticks of the current date then divide by 10000 since there are 10000 ticks in a milisecond.  This will give you a number which should be easier to serialize.  You could make this an extension method of DateTime.  Ticks on MSDN:
[DateTime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The other option is use a TimeSpan and use TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: Looking back at your original question I have the answer for how to do the date math, but your specific question is for default serialization of DateTime.    So you can probably ignore these.

Comment: its not about date math, its about customixing the asp.net serializer to yeild numbers of toal milliseconds since 1970 instead of an iso date strings for DateTime values

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this excellent blog post](https://cgeers.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/writing-a-custom-json-net-datetime-converter/) on creating your own DateTime converter to deal with your requirement. Example actually shows you creating UnixDateTimeConverter.

Comment: so you want me to annotate every single date time property with an attribute? thats way too much work

Comment: You are not forced to use attributes, instead you can use IContractResolver to do this automatically. Look at the [official documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) of how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the easiest way, but you can create a custom converter for DateTimes, then a custom JsonMediaTypeFormatter which uses that converter.

```
// This class overrides conversion for DateTime values
public class MyDateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Your algorithm here
        var customValue = ((DateTime)value).Ticks;
        writer.WriteValue(customValue);
    }
}

// This formatter will create serializers with the above converter injected
public class MyJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override JsonSerializer CreateJsonSerializer()
    {
        var serializer = base.CreateJsonSerializer();
        serializer.Converters.Add(new MyDateConverter());
        return serializer;
    }
}

// Inside your WebApi config code, replace the default formatter with your custom one
var defaultJsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
config.Formatters.Remove(defaultJsonFormatter);
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyJsonFormatter());
```